# What is the strumming pattern for this cover (Under the Sea guitar cover)?

Tags: guitar

What is the strumming pattern for this cover of Under the Sea?  There seems to be a percussive hit in there but it could just be my amateur ears.  And it seems he just using his index finger to strum?

Comment: There;s a percussive aspect to the strumming (as there always is) and he's using his thumb and index finger to strum. I'm not sure I understand the question. The strumming pattern is the one he's using.

Comment: @PeterJ "The strumming pattern is the one he's using"  Very helpful /s.  I think you know what I mean

Comment: I wan't being rude. I was wondering how it would be possible to explain the strumming any better than the video demonstrates it. Basically you move your hand up and down like he does. There's no special technique here but just up and down strumming. .

Comment: @PeterJ Just looking at the hand movement often isn't accurate though since you might be moving your hand up and down to keep the beat but not strumming.  Faith by George Michael is a good example of what I mean.  And unfortunately my amateur ears aren't good enough to distinguish these patterns yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, fair enough, perhaps my first comment was rather pointless. If you'd played George Michael's 'Faith' it would have been a different comment. What this guy is doing is just strumming up and down and using the back of his hand to damp the strings.

To do this requires that you strum with the back of your RH close to the strings. If you rest the back edge of your hand on the bridge far enough back that the strings are not damped and strum up and down and then gently bring your hand forward until it starts to damp the strings you'll get the idea.

If you simply have fun strumming and damping for a while you'll start getting a feel for it. For a masterly demonstration there is always Niles Rodgers.

I'd suggest just repeating a note on the open 6th string and getting the hang of damping, then try it with the open E and a B on the 5th string (a 'power chord') and then all the strings.

This sort of damping is crucial on an electric, especially a high volumes. It's the key to funkiness.

Usually the RH is just going up and down and the rhythmic interest comes from damping, stressing certain beats and missing the odd up or down stroke. Still, it's just up and down.

This guy is placing his thumb and first finger together and using his first finger as a pick. This is the best idea with nylon strings to save damage and for a certain sound but not so good on steel.

This is most definitely not rocket-science and if you just strum away for a while it should come naturally.